# Empty white space when plotting with Geopandas

Tags: graph, maps, geopandas

I am using Google Colab to try to plot some Geospatial data following this tutorial:
[Tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/redlining-mapping-inequality-in-peer-2-peer-lending-using-geopandas-part-2-9d8af584df0b)

Using the US Census .shp file:
[File](https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_zcta510_500k.zip)
this is the head of the data:
[df_head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZ5ED.png)
and the .crs:
[crs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R87Tc.png)

However every time I try to plot I get these weird empty spaces that looks like it's trying to plot the whole world map on the overlay like this:
[Geopandas Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inkue.png)

My code is as simple as:

```
df_zipcodes = geopandas.read_file('cb_2018_us_zcta510_500k.shp')
df_zipcodes.plot()
```

Any thoughts? I tried changing the crs of the file but did not succeed, also I cleared and closed all figures before trying a new plot.

Comment: Clearly, there are some small lands on the other part of the dateline.

Comment: Thanks man, that was it, I just had to apply a filter beforehand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was trying to use the same filter as indicated in the tutorial:

```
df_states[~df_states['STUSPS'].isin(['AK','HI','AA','AE','AP','PR','RI','VI'])]
```

But in reality I had to apply:

```
df_states[~df_states['STUSPS'].isin(['PR', 'AK','VI','HI','AS','GU','MP'])]
```